# Mercurial. Не получается залить проект

Tags: mercurial

Привет. Проблема заключается в том, что я немогу залить проект на битбакет. Коммиты делаются в локальном репозитории. Всё хорошо. Но если я пытаюсь заливать его на битбакет, то загрузка подвисает вот в этот момент.

https://pp.vk.me/c627918/v627918281/11fa1/DRFoEnGGhdo.jpg

Я пробовал пересоздавать репозиторий у себя на компе путём копирования в новую папку .hg .

Пробовал создавать новый репозиторий в облаке и заливать туда.

Проблема не уходит.

Что делать?

Comment: Может, у вас интернет худой, а проект на пару сотен гиг?
Попробуйте с пустым.

Comment: До этого всё заливалось нормально. Проект на 100мб, не больше. Но с определённой версии всё поломалось. Такое ощущение, что одна, конкретная ревизия всё портит.

Comment: Для добавления картинок пожалуйста используйте кнопку с картинкой в режиме редактирования. Со сторонних хостингов картинки могут когда-нибудь удалиться.

Comment: На английском стеке мне не позволено добавлять картинки из-за низкого рейтинга. Здесь я сделал ссылкой по тем же причинам.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для начала посмотрите лог на своём сервере. У битбакет такой возможности вероятно нет, но можно написать в поддержку.

Есть вероятность, что проблема может быть связана не с самим мерком, а с ssh, пробегитесь тут:

https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/troubleshoot-ssh-issues-271943403.html#TroubleshootSSHIssues-pushinganewrepositoryissloworhangs

Если не слишком критична история правок, я бы создал новый репозитарий, с целью быстро продолжить работу.

Comment: Скорее всего так и сделаю -- пересоздам репозиторий. Что касается ssh, а разве там не по http? Я в протоколах ничегошеньки не смыслю, то всегда, когда указываю адрес репозитория в Tortoise, прописываю http.